# Error when typing "git commit"?

Tags: android, git, github, commit, repo

I'm building a ROM but I need a commit into `/frameworks/base` repo. So i "`git fetch`" the Github repo and then I type "`git commit xxxxx`", but the output is:

> error: pathspec xxxxx did not match any file(s) known to git.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do these things in order..

**Fetch All Branches**

```
git fetch --all
```

**Check Branch Name**

```
git branch
```

**Then Checkout to branch**

```
git checkout your_branch_name
```

**Now, while committing**

1. Add all files you want to commit in the staging area

   `git add .` (for all files)

   `git add filename` (for respective file)
2. Commit to local database

`git commit -m "your custom message"`

3. Push to remote repo

`git push origin current_branch_name`

Here, origin is the remote name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git checkout -b yourbranchname
```

And then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify some concepts of git before using.

1) 'git fetch' only update those refs to remote branches, it do not merge remote modifications to your worktree. You need run 'git pull' to merge with your worktree.

2) you need a branch to work on. You can run 'git checkout -b' to create a new one, or 'git checkout --track' to create one tracking remote branch.